# Bootstrap 4 Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How to create a space between a Bootstrap 4 navbar logo and navbar list items?

I want a `navbar-brand` (logo) at the left-most side and a `navbar-list-items` on the right-most side in a container.

That's it.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems are you running into?

Comment: i tried everthing

Comment: i need nav bar like this for example

Oppo                                                             Home About  Contact US

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same template for the component from the official docs, and just add a `ml-auto` class to the list container so it aligns everything to the right.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"> <!-- Add this class to the list container -->
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the following worked for me.

1. Add 'container-fluid' or 'container'

```
<ul class="navbar-nav container-fluid">
...
```

2. Add 'ml-auto' to the nav items you want aligned on the right

```
<li class='nav-item ml-auto'><a href="#">Item</a></li>
```